# How to set bar width with datetime values on x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

**PROBLEM:**

I found a lot of answers regarding this topic here but none of them worked. I read that matplotlib transforms the date axis into a range object. So as I have monthly data, a bar `width=1` would mean a width of 1 month which actually works perfectly:

[image]

but as soon as I set `width=0.99` or any value lower than 1, I get a totally messed bar chart, where I just wanted to be able to precisely control the bar width or at least add some gaps between each bar, so it might even be possible to add quarterly bar charts to a plot of monthly data.

[image]

where data is a pandas series with monthly dates as index values.

**MWE:**

```
                chart1  chart2
Date                                                                         
2019-01-31                                    0.208545               0.117835
2019-02-28                                    1.045836               0.008659
2019-03-31                                    1.977714               0.996313
2019-04-30                                    3.647403               1.528709
2019-05-31                                    3.583291               2.079429
2019-06-30                                    4.593321               4.294865
2019-07-31                                    6.617398               6.073648
2019-08-31                                    9.189794               8.488473
2019-09-30                                   10.216717               8.845000
2019-10-31                                    9.994394               8.200474
2019-11-30                                    9.636940               6.949948
2019-12-31                                   10.294149               6.437733
2020-01-31                                   11.038578               6.785553
2020-02-29                                   13.008305               8.519324
2020-03-31                                    9.460242               7.218570
2020-04-30                                   11.023622               5.639113
2020-05-31                                   11.779224               6.159791
```

copy this dataframe and then use the following code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(data.index, data['chart1'].to_list())
ax.bar(data.index, data['chart2'].to_list(), width=0.99)
```

**SOLUTION:**

The problem seemed to be as the frequency of the DatetimeIndex object was set to `'M'` for monthly, it is not possible to choose a bar width smaller than that frequency. If you want to make the Bars smaller you need to change that frequency first:

```
data.index.freq = None
```

The data itself stays unchanged, but now the unit for bar `width` is set to days and you can use any number between 1 and 30 to have gaps between your bars.

Comment: Could you please provide an MWE? But judging from your description, it wouldn't really make sense to define the intervals smaller than 1. Is your question actually about the visual representation of those intervals rather than changing the intervals themselves?

Comment: I have added a working MWE. The problem comes with the datetime index. Reading the Index as string values, the bar width is adjustable. But I need the datetime index as I might mix quarterly with monthly data etc.

Comment: Thank you! If your MWE actually works, try to change it iteratively to match your actual code and check at what point the behaviour changes. This should bring you closer to identifying the problem.

Comment: I got the MWE working now, so the error is reproducable. By doing that I also figured out what the problem was. I needed to change the frequency of the DatetimeIndex object which was used to create the x axis. I added a Solution to the question as well.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You can post the solution as an answer yourself and accept it. As far as I know, that is actually the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the frequency of the DatetimeIndex object is set to `'M'` for monthly as the data is also on a monthly basis.
It is not possible to choose a bar width smaller than that frequency. If you want to make the Bars smaller you need to change that frequency first:

```
data.index.freq = None
```

Other options are 'W', 'M', 'Q', 'A' or 'D'. You can always use None (which means daily), the rest of the options needs to fit with the data. The data itself stays unchanged if you use None, but now the unit for bar `width` is set to days and you can use any number between 1 and 30 to have create gaps between your bars.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.index.freq = None
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(15.6/2.54, 12/2.54))
ax.plot(data.index, data['chart1'].to_list())
ax.bar(data.index, data['chart2'].to_list(), width=20)
```